# Problem with recursion on java and Array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, recursion

I need to resolve this exercise for my studies.
Answer:Write a recursion method on Java that give in input one array of Strings [][] "a" and as output one array of Strings [][] "b" where every elements b[i][j] it's a concatenation of two elements of a as a[i][j].concat(a[i][j+1]).

My code:

```
public static String [][] concatena (String [][] a) {
    String [][] b = new String [a.length][];
        return concatena(a,b,0,0);
    }

public static String [][] concatena (String [][] a,String [][] b, int i, int j) {
    if (i == a.length)
        return b;

    if (j == 0)
    b[i] = new String [a[i].length-1];
    
    if (j > 0 )
        b[i][j] = a[i][j].concat(a[i][j+1]);
            return concatena(a,b,i,j+1);
            
    if (j == a[i].length-1) 
        return concatena(a,b,i+1,0);
            b[i][j] = a[i][j].concat(a[i][j+1]);
                return concatena(a,b,i,j+1);
 
 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [][] a = {{"aa","cde","run","kdef"},{"stk","beta"},{"rho","p","alfa"}};
    b = concatena(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question? I only see a goal and some code with no details about what your problem is and what you're stuck on.

Comment: When try run my code don't have nothing. I think that my code don't run right because the elements b[i][j] are not created.

Answer (score 0):

The variable b is not declared in main method so you need to **initialize the b** in the main method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [][] a = {{"aa","cde","run","kdef"},{"stk","beta"},{"rho","p","alfa"}};
    b = concatena(a); <---------
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

There's no variable initialised with this name so I'm wondering if it even compiles.

You need to initialise or at least tell the program which type is going to be this "b" variable

```
String [][] b = new String [a.length][]
```

So your `main` method should be like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [][] a = {{"aa","cde","run","kdef"},{"stk","beta"},{"rho","p","alfa"}};
    String [][] b = concatena(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

But even if you fix this your compiler is going to complain because this part of code is unreachable statement.

```
if (j == a[i].length-1) 
        return concatena(a,b,i+1,0);
            b[i][j] = a[i][j].concat(a[i][j+1]);
                return concatena(a,b,i,j+1);
```